# Unable to separate header & cpp file (error and code included)

Tags: c++, class, linker-errors

So here are the files in my code. It compiles fine if I comment out all of the data.cpp and paste the functions inside the data.h header file under the class. But when I do it so it's separate I get this error.

```
duplicate symbol _salesData in:.../SalesData.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
.../SalesData.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Data.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

So I remove the #include "data.h" on main.cpp and comment out the function calls and it compiles but it obviously doesn't do what I want it to do then. I don't understand how I have duplicate symbols.
Here are my files...

```
//data.h
#ifndef __SalesData__Data__
#define __SalesData__Data__

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Data {
public:
    //[0] = day DD, [1] = month MM, [2] = year YYYY
    float data[32][13][9999];
    void newData();
    void editData();
    float viewData();
}salesData;

#endif /* defined(__SalesData__Data__) */
```

...

```
//data.cpp
#include "Data.h"

void Data::editData() {
    unsigned short day;
    unsigned short month;
    unsigned short year;
    float dailySales;
    printf("\nSelect Day: ");
    printf("\n>> ");
    std::cin >> day;
    printf("\nSelect Month: ");
    printf("\n>> ");
    std::cin >> month;
    printf("\nSelect Year: ");
    printf("\n>> ");
    std::cin >> year;
    printf("\nEnter Daily Sales: ");
    printf("\n>> ");
    if ((data[day][month][year])) {
        std::cin >> dailySales;
        data[day][month][year] = dailySales;
    }
    else {
        printf("\nSales have not been recorded for this date. If you wish to input type 'yes' else press any other key");
        std::string choice;
        std::cin >> choice;
        if (choice == "yes") {
            newData();
        }
    }
}
//... same for other class functions
```

...

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Data.h"

void selectMain() {

    char choice;
    while (1) {
        printf("Please select an option.");
        printf("\n1. Input Data");
        printf("\n2. View Data");
        printf("\n3. Edit Data");
        printf("\n>> ");
        std::cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
            case '1':
                salesData.newData();
                return;
            case '2':
                salesData.viewData();
                return;
            case '3':
                salesData.editData();
                return;
            default:
                printf("\nInvalid Choice. ");
                continue;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char endChar;
    while (endChar != '`') {
        selectMain();
        printf("\nPress any key to continue or '`' to end the program.\n");
        std::cin >> endChar;
    }
    printf("\nProgram Ended");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a make file error not a code error...

Comment: In here, `class Data { ... }salesData;` what's that `salesData` doing at the end? And whatever it is that it's doing, do you think you should be doing it in two different files in the same program?

Comment: @Scott: Right. That's why you have duplicate symbols.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I assumed that it would only create 1 instance by declaring it after the class. Thanks for pointing by error out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is cause the way you define variable *salesData* in header file, after class declaration. Because of this it gets defined both in *data.cpp* file and in your *main.cpp* file. Move the *salesData* variable to the *main.cpp*

Comment: Or declare it `extern` in the header and define it in one of the other two files.

Comment: `extern` was the easiest way to go by putting it in the data.h file. Thanks Johnathan & Paul.